# OpenLayers 2 navigation history in OpenLayers 3

Tags: navigation, history, openlayers-3

I did not found Openlayers 3 navigation history control.

How can I use OpenLayers 3 view history like in OpenLayers 2 navigation history?

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble implementing it. This is what is working for me...

```
var history = [];
var history_now = -1;
var click = false;
var delay = 350; // OpenLayers render delay = 250

// On view change
map.on('moveend', function (e) {

    // Do not save view history if previous/next was clicked
    if (click) return;
    history.push({
        center: map.getView().getCenter(), 
        resolution: map.getView().getResolution()
    });
    history_now++;
});

// On previous button click
$('.action-nav-previous').on('click', function () {
    if (history_now > 0) {
        click = true;
        history_now--;
        map.getView().setCenter(history[history_now].center);
        map.getView().setResolution(history[history_now].resolution);
        setTimeout(function () {
            click = false;
        }, delay);
    }
});

// On next button click...
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen for change events on the view and implement it in your application code.